# Перевод времени из input type=date в нормальный вид (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, нормальный скрипт, который будет переводить дату в нормальный вид на js. Нужно для input'ов, на данный момент все идет в формате для MySQL - 2017-07-18. Есть похожий скрипт на php, но не хочется ajax ради такой фигни делать, + костыль получается).

Желательно, чтобы выводил в формате "18 июля 2017".

Comment: А куда нужно выводить отформатированную дату? В `input type="date"` возможет только формат `дд.мм.гггг`

Comment: @Cheg просто нужна функция на js/jQuery, которая будет принимать входным параметром дату и возвращать дату в формате, который в тексте указан)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```js
var date = new Date($('input[type="date"]').val());
var options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
};
var dateStr = date.toLocaleString('ru', options);
dateStr = dateStr.replace(' г.',''); // если нужно обрезать ' г.' на конце
console.log(dateStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" value="2017-07-18">
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!)